# Matplot drawing rainbow lines to X-axis without request

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Matplotlib has started drawing rainbow lines to the X-axis without request. Sometimes it still draws the normal plot, but often not.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib
G=numpy.zeros(100)
for i in range(50):
    G[i+50]=50-i
    matplotlib.pyplot.plot(G)
```

[image]

What is causing this behavior and how do I turn it off permanently? I have the latest version  of matplotlib installed, running python 3.6, anaconda distribution `4.5.5`.

Comment: try making G a list? I mean plot `list(G)` instead? Anyway I didn't have this output with the same code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might have added a little indentation before your plot function.

While

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=numpy.zeros(100)
for i in range(50):
    G[i+50]=50-i

plt.plot(G)
plt.show()
```

produces this:

[image]

with a little more indentation:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
G=numpy.zeros(100)
for i in range(50):
    G[i+50]=50-i

    plt.plot(G)
plt.show()
```

will produce the rainbow lines

[image]

Comment: @JackJadon Thanks!!! So simple... Is this a new feature? Never noticed it before.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a feature. What you are doing is essentially running plot after each time you set a new value in G. Therefore it produces lots of lines in your plot. In the long term, you should avoid it, as it may cause some weird behaviours.